# How to know the front end server infromation

Tags: lync

I am trying to analyze the QoE metric of lync monitoring server. 
Is there any way to retrieve the FE server information that handled the call from QoEmetric database?

Thanks in advance

Dipankaj

Answer (score 0):

These two posts on the Lync developer forums might help:

[QoE database access](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/aa4fa7a6-3237-45ad-a2f3-783b15a552a5/qoe-database-access?forum=communicationsserversdk)

[OCS Database Schema R2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/fa1e0f6f-a72b-4dce-9e16-ab82fd2bd26f/ocs-database-schema-r2?forum=communicationsserversdk)